# Parsing data in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I m using NSURLRequest to get and post data from server.
but after processing returned is in html format how i parse it.

Untitled Document

30

please give any refrence.

i want use 30 in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use libxml2, which is part of the iOS SDK.